# Shortcut to extend length of still image clip in Premiere?

Tags: premiere

I'm using Adobe Premiere Pro CC 2015.  As an example of a common scenario, on a single video track I'll have two still images (e.g. jpg files) with some space between them.  Image1 first followed by some space and then Image2.

What I'd like to do is extend the duration of Image1 so that it fills the space and ends where Image2 begins.

Before:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
   +---------------+             +-------------------+    
   | Image 1       |             | Image 2           |    
   |               |             |                   |    
   +---------------+             +-------------------+    
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

After:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------+
   +---------------------------+ +-------------------+    
   | Image 1                   | | Image 2           |    
   |                           | |                   |    
   +---------------------------+ +-------------------+    
+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

Obviously I can do this with the mouse and drag the edge of Image1 over to Image2.  However is there a keyboard shortcut that will automatically do this?

Comment: I should specify I'm on Windows

Answer (score 3):

As happens, the act of asking a questions leads me to the answer faster.  I can do this with a combination of two shortcuts:

1. <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> (Go to Next Edit Point)
2. <kbd>Shift + Q</kbd> (Extend Previous Edit To Playhead)

(Still be interested if there's a way to do this with a single shortcut)

Comment: I didn't know about Shift+Q. Thanks for posting this answer for the rest of us!

Comment: `Shift + Q` to extend to the playhead the clip left of the playhead. `Shift + W` to extend to the playhead the clip located right of the playhead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

1. Put the still image on the track as usual.
2. Click the end of the region, so it turns red.

[image]

3. Move your timeline cursor to the end of your edit.

[image]

4. Press <kbd>E</kbd>

[image]
The bug is extended to the end with no dragging